# Instance id in spring boot admin is same for 2 services, can someone suggest me how to create a unique one

Tags: java, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I have 2 replica of a single spring boot services with same service url and context path and they are running on 2 different pods and i have registered both the services to spring boot admin ui but there instance id is same can someone suggest me how to create a unique one,
due to this I am not able to change logs as it is causing issues with communication between the Spring Boot Admin Server and the instances.

I have already tried to change some metadata but no luck so far.

Can we set a custom instance ID that is unique for each instance of my service in spring boot admin server itself.

Comment: How did you register the services with Spring Boot Admin? It shouldn't be possible to register two different services and get the same instance ID.

Comment: suppose we have a service which we have deployed on 2 different servers but to access them we use a service url, for example, name of my service is abc and I am accessing it via example.com/abc and it is decided automatically that on which server or pod the request will go according to load balancer, and in our case we are not allowed to use ip-address to access that server via spring-boot-admin-server so we are using example.com/abc/health to register and thus we are getting same instance id

Comment: It makes no sense to register two different services with the same health URL, because SBA will not know which of the two services it reaches when checking that health URL. You _must_ have a distinct health URL for every service if you want to use SBA.